# How to split the column into two under same column name and having same values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I am trying to split (internal split) a column so that there are two columns under the same column name and both those column should have the same values.

I am trying to implement the following in Python using Pandas library

Say My data-frame looks like this

> ```
>         Column1  Column2
> Row1       1        2
> Row2       3        4
> ```

Desired Output:

> ```
>          Column1  Column2
>  Row1     1 | 1    2 | 2
>  Row2     3 | 3    4 | 4
> ```

Comment: Please include a sample dataframe and expected output. This is not a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question.

Comment: I think you want to have a MultiIndexed dataframe, have a look [here][1] to see how that works.


  [1]: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we begin with your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [1, 3],
                   'Column2': [2,4]},
                  index = ['Row1', 'Row2'])

df

      Column1   Column2
Row1        1         2
Row2        3         4
```

1. Use pd.concat and interleave methods to make a duplicate of each column and ensure that each column's duplicate appears just to its right:

```
from toolz import interleave
df = pd.concat([df, df], axis=1)[list(interleave([df]))]
```

At this point, the dataframe looks like:

```
df

     Column1 Column1 Column2 Column2
Row1       1       1       2       2
Row2       3       3       4       4
```

2. Now change the dataframe's columns to a MultiIndex:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Column1', 'Column2'], ['A', 'B']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Which results in a dataframe that now appears like this:

```
df

        Column1   Column2
        A   B     A   B
Row1    1   1     2   2
Row2    3   3     4   4
```

Comment: Thanks James Dellinger, you saved my day.

Comment: No problem, it was my pleasure to be able to help out! It was a chance for me to learn a lot about `pd.MultiIndex` works, especially how the `labels` argument works.